# Natural ordering of elements in priority queue

Tags: java, scjp

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), priority queue elements are ordered according to natural ordering then how come it prints in a different way

```
public class PQ2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    pq.add(2);
    pq.add(4);
    System.out.println(pq);
    pq.offer(1);
    System.out.println(pq);
    pq.add(3);
    System.out.println(pq);
}
}
```

Comment: The doc states: _"Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order."_ Since `toString()` uses the iterator to build the content into a String, you cannot make any assumptions.

Comment: @AlexisC. Seriously? This is question from scjp kathy& berts. How I'm I suppose to answer it? Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Page 654 chapter 7. I am updating the question in a sec

Comment: Updated it. Now look at the actual question which is similar to what I have asked

Comment: But they use `peek` and `poll` which have a well defined behavior. This has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Actual answer is 2 2 3 4 however when I am trying to figure out the answer with out using IDE(as in the exam-scenario) how would figure the ordering of elements? I have find the order first to get the actual answer which is impossible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77078/discussion-between-kittu-and-alexis-c).

Answer (score 1):

The order the elements are printed is determined by the iterator of the `PriorityQueue` class, which is not ordered:

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator
 * does not return the elements in any particular order.
 *
 * @return an iterator over the elements in this queue
 */
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

`PriorityQueue` uses the `toString()` implementation of `AbstractCollection`, which uses the `iterator()` method to iterate over the elements.

This has nothing to do with the order the elements will be removed from the queue, which is according to the natural ordering.